# What use has the default (assembly).dll.config file for .NET-Assemblies?

Tags: c#, xml, configuration-files

I have a question regarding AppSettings in C#.
First I´ll describe my situation.

My solution consists of an executable program `program.exe` and an `assembly.dll`.

The program references the assembly and works with it. The assembly-project has application settings set up with the Visual Studio project settings manager. Now when I compile my solution in my `assembly\bin\release` folder there is an `assembly.dll.config` file which contains the settings I have set up earlier.

Now the thing I don´t understand : in my program-project where I reference the `assembly.dll` I have checked `CopyLocal=True`, but in my `program\bin\release` folder there is only the `assembly.dll` but not the assembly.dll.config file BUT STILL the `assembly.dll` knows the settings I have set up in the assembly-project application settings.

Now I have read several times that assemblies always access the settings of the executable program but the program has no corresponding settings, so why does the assembly know the correct settings when there is no `assembly.dll.config` file present?

I assume the settings are compiled into the assembly at compiletime (of course), but then it makes no sense that in my assembly\bin\release folder there actually IS an assembly.dll.config file.

I tried copying this file into my `program\bin\release` folder where the `assembly.dll` is copied to on build action, but the `assembly.dll` just ignores if there is an `assembly.dll.config` file present in the same folder. It always uses the settings from compiletime. I just don´t understand the use of the `assembly.dll.config` file. Why is it created when it never has impact on the `assembly.dll´s` behaviour ?

Comment: Do you have a program.exe.config file in there as well though? Have the settings been merged into that?

Comment: Yes my program.exe also has a config file but it contains only the configurations for the program. They are totally different from the assembly´s configuration so I can say taht for sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default values are built into the .dll file. You can of course still change those settings, but you do that in the program.exe config instead by referring to the assembly settings with a section in `configSections`/`sectionGroup`. The assembly settings can then be changed in the `applicationSettings` by creating a XML block with the same name as the section.

The section tag in the section group can simply be copied from the app.config file of your assembly project. That way the token, name, etc. will be correct. The same goes for the applicationSettings part. Just copy it from the app.config in the assembly project and into the app.config file of the program.exe project.

example program.exe.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    ... references to all dll settings ...
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="MyAssemblyNamespace.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  ... more config stuff...
  <applicationSettings>
    ... override your dll settings ...
    <MyAssemblyNamespace.Properties.Settings>
       <setting name="MaxUserNameLength" serializeAs="String">
          <value>100</value>
       </setting>
    </MyAssemblyNamespace.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

Comment: You are right. Copying my assembly settings into the program.exe.config works and the assembly uses these settings. So I assume the automatic creation of the assembly.dll.config file is for the sole purpose of copying things out to another config-file ?

Comment: Visual Studio can also detect if your assembly .config and .settings gets out of sync in which case it will offer to synchronize the files for you. That means that you can go the other way too: Tweak your settings in the program settings and easily copy the values back as new default values.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, this doesn't seem to work anymore. For me it fails with this error: "Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section applicationSettings/MyAssemblyNamespace.Properties.Settings."

Answer (score 1):

It's valid for an assembly  to open any config file it likes using the [OpenExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. This way that can access their own config rather than the one implicitly available from the executing assembly. This isn't commonly done, but there's nothing to stop you doing it.

If your assembly is functioning correctly without the config file then it sounds like it has a sensible set of default value that it uses when it cant find the appropriate configuration.