# in a .netcore assembly bin folder, what is the use of the ".dll.config" file?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-core

I have a .netcore assembly with an added app.config file in the project, along with a config file in the bin folder titled "assemblyname.dll.config". It contains the appsettings included in the app.config file.

What is the purpose of the "assemblyname.dll.config" file in the assembly bin folder, and how does a .netcore assembly use it?

Comment: Check this answer out and the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21627819/2093880

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how i missed that.